# Is "!$a==$b" faster then "$a != $b"?

Tags: php, operators

I was reading a PHP book about operators.

And the book says that `if(!$a == $b)` is faster then `if($a != $b)`.
Is this true?

I have tried this with MS but with no results. What do you think?

**EDIT:**
`if($a != $b)` is faster then `if(!$a == $b)`

Comment: Which book were you reading? I can say for sure, that "!==" is faster than "!=" - maybe this was the example given by the book?

Comment: The speed difference on any primitive type, if there is any at all, is going to be in nanoseconds.  If the compiler does no optimisation, `!=` should be faster, as `!( == )` is two operations.

Comment: A swedish book. But I don't know. I did try it with microseconds with no results.

Comment: !$a or !($a because I have this nagging feeling there is a loophole on the one you posted

Comment: A Swedish book? Why not name it?

Comment: Those two statements can have different outcomes depending on the operators, PHP is a bitch in that regard.

Comment: Because you can't find it on internet..

Comment: A book on PHP that you can't find on the internet? Really??

Comment: Yes, I can't find it. Maybe not published yet, It's a brand new book!

Comment: @hazard: Honestly, if it is a book and you cannot find it on the Internet, it means it is so unpopular and unknown, that you really should not trust it. Anyone can print his own book, but it does not make the content trustworthy.

Comment: and thats y we got stackoverflow :)

Comment: @hazard is it too hazardous to give the name of the unfamous book?

Comment: Yes, maybe.. The name is: "PHP - Direct" (Swedish Book)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over 1,000,000 iterations, I found that `if( $a != $b)` is about 40% slower than `if( !$a == $b)`, however this difference is only about 0.04 nanoseconds, and they are NOT equivalent.

```
$a = "123";
$b = 456;
var_dump(
    $a != $b, // true
    !$a == $b // false
);
```

Comment: Ah, here you have a type conversion possibly going on as well, rather complicates the question.

Answer (score 10):

It may seem a paradox, but these statements are not equivalent:

```
$a = '0';
$b = null;

var_dump(!$a == $b); // false
var_dump($a != $b); // true
```

... because of non-transitive type coercion. Hence talking about speed doesn't make any sense here.

**UPDATE:** Perhaps this should be explained as well. ) The first comparison will be evaluated as...

```
(!'0') == null;
```

In other words, first `'0'` will get converted to `boolean` (which results in `false`; note the difference with JavaScript). And `!false` evaluates to `true`, of course, - which just cannot be equal to `null` in any language (*but in fact* `null` *gets converted to boolean too, only then these values will be compared*).

In the second comparison `'0'` (a string) is compared with `null` - and suddenly rules are [changed](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.types). `null` gets converted to an empty string (!), and this empty string is what will be actually compared with `'0'`. Needless to say, these are not equal too.

The bottom line is that you should be very careful when fiddling with comparison operators for speed. It may cause very subtle - and very different to track - bugs.

Comment: ! operator has precedence over the ==  Clearly they are not the same

Comment: Hmm. Why is the first operator false?

Comment: @HernanVelasquez And did I say the opposite? ) With _most_ data the example in question works indeed, because, well `(!true == false)` is the same as `(true != false)`.

Comment: @hazard Because `!'0'` evaluates to `true` (as `(bool)'0'` evaluates to `false`)

Comment: No you didn't.  You were right on you appreciation and that what I meant :)

Answer (score 2):

Edit: No, after a few times it seems to make no difference at all:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/09c03d21b5dfe626d6a5c4791b94ac49e2d4fa1a

Click execute a few times, no difference.

first test: 0.075621128082275
second test: 0.080623149871826

about 0.005 secs slower on average with a million iterations.

Comment: Depends on how you want to look at it . ..  .it's arguably twice as fast, which is a lot.

Comment: first test: 0.0058829784393311 second test: 0.0055069923400879 
I had this result. in my case its allways slower

Comment: What other not-like things can we compare?